# Optimizing tensorflow to CPU use

Tags: optimization, tensorflow, cpu, convolution

I have a model that needs to be optimized to CPU.

Currently the model takes a 1024 x 1024 bytes data.

```
images = img[y:y+1024,x:x+1024,:]
```

As per this document, they want to change the default tensorflow data format from `NHCW` to `NCHW` format.

How can I transform from `NHWC` to `NCHW` format?

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/tensorflow-optimizations-on-modern-intel-architecture

Answer (score 1):

> As per this document, they want to change the default tensorflow data format from NHCW to NCHW format.

Actually, I've never seen any Tensorflow function that supports `NHCW` format. For example, [`tf.nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) and [`tf.nn.conv2d_transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d_transpose) support `NHWC` (current default) and `NCHW` format. [`tf.nn.max_pool`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/max_pool) supports  `NHWC`, `NCHW` and `NCHW_VECT_C` (the last one is the most performant tensor format for cudnn6's quantized convolution, similar to `NCHW`).

> How can I transform from NHCW to NCHW format?

But this transformation is possible, e.g. via [`tf.transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) that works with high-dimensional tensors as well:

```py
# NHCW
original = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1024, 3, 1024])
# NCHW: swap 1 and 2 axis
transformed = tf.transpose(original, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])
```

You can also do this in numpy via `np.swapaxes(array, 1, 2)`.

Comment: Thanks, I have provided the document link.

Comment: OK. I guess you meant NHWC, because it says "TensorFlow default NHWC format is not the most efficient ...", which seems to be true. Anyway, the proposed solution should work