# CNN: Why is the image matrix transformed to (channel, width, height)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution, mxnet

I am going through some CNN articles. I see that they transform the input image to `(channel, width, height)`.

A code example taken from [MXNET CNN Tutorial](http://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter04_convolutional-neural-networks/cnn-scratch.html).

```
def transform(data, label):
  # 2,0,1 means channels,width, height
  return nd.transpose(data.astype(np.float32), (2,0,1))/255, label.astype(np.float32)
```

Can any one explain why do we do this transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several image formats for 2-dimensional convolution, the main ones are:

- **Channel-first** or `NCHW` format, i.e., `(batch, channels, height, width)`.
- **Channel-last** or `NHWC` format, i.e., `(batch, height, width, channels)`.

They are basically equivalent and can be easily converted from one to another, though there is evidence that certain low-level implementations perform more efficiently when a particular data format is used (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47351372/712995)).

Computational engines usually accept both formats, but have different defaults, e.g.,

- Tensorflow [accepts both](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/convolution) and uses `NHWC` by default.
- Theano [accepts](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/conv.html#theano.tensor.nnet.conv2d) only `NCHW` format.
- Keras also works with both and has a [dedicated setting](https://keras.io/backend/#kerasjson-details) for it. The latest version also uses `NHWC` by default.
- MXNet [accepts both formats](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/symbol.html#mxnet.symbol.Convolution) too, but the default is `NCHW`:

  > The default data layout is `NCHW`, namely `(batch_size, channel, height, width)`. We can choose other layouts such as `NHWC`.

This default is pretty much the only reason to reshape the tensors, simply to avoid `layout` argument in the network.